# Unable to call $on from other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
(function(app) {


app.config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //region Registering States

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  var dashboard = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
  };

  var home = {
    name: 'profile',
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    controller: 'profileCtrl'
  };



  $stateProvider.state(dashboard);
  $stateProvider.state(home);
  //endregion



});

app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', function($rootScope,$scope) {

   $rootScope.pageTitle = "home";
   $scope.callEvent = function(){
     $rootScope.$broadcast('newEvent',"data");
   }


}]);

 console.log('called');
}(angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])));
```

2'nd controller:

```
(function(app) {
app.controller('profileCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', function($rootScope,$scope) {

  $rootScope.pageTitle = "profile";

  $rootScope.$on('newEvent',function(ev,data){
    alert('Event fired from home');
  });


  $scope.$on('newEvent',function(ev,data){
    alert('Event fired from home');
  });

}]);
 }(angular.module('app')));
```

App with 2 controller:

1 controller:  fired a event using $broadcast

2 controller: capturing event fired from 1'st controller.
But unable to accomplish that.

**NOTE:** If html page load once( 2'nd controller), $on event is fired else it's doesn't listen to any event.

**For better understanding i had created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CgyBQx9K4tbqvJarmdNF?p=preview)**

**Please first review the code**

@vojta

Thanks

Comment: Imagine you have tons of pages. I doubt angular will load all of those at once, so I guess this behavior is expected.

Comment: If you always need to handle an event, no matter where you are, you can register the `$on` inside `app.run()`. Or, you could simply have a service handling the event, and the `ProfileController` checking what's inside this service

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are loading the controllers via states. This means they only initialize once the state becomes active (i.e you navigate to the html).

If you add a console log to profileCtrl you see that it does not get fired until the page is active.

Comment: Suggest `app.run()` to complete the answer, Working example https://plnkr.co/edit/oZJkmBY3k8vYVTHOdz4N?p=preview

Comment: @dcrux Thanks, but is there any solution for that ?

Comment: I'm unsure. Could look into loading the profileCtrl as part of the homeCtrl route resolve.  For me the question is this event needed? The two controllers might not have to be coupled in this way.  Is it an option to have the homeCtrl act upon a service? And use this service to drive how the profileCtrl is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't load the controller if it wasn't called.
Think of it as a singleton object which won't init until you will try to run it.

In your case, you set a controller for a specific route which means it will run only after you go to its route address.

What you actually will want to do is to have some directive [Angular Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
That will control on your menu bar that you will load on the main page and maybe every other page.
And for the home page, you should have a different controller that will be active only when the user is on the page.

As a side note, don't assume the "home" controller will be available once you leave the home page ([Angular destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy)).